# tab separating the values

Tags: perl, bash, shell

I have a set of values in a column stored in a txt file,

```
A13R
W234H
Q1H
```

What I want is to separate the first character and last character by a tab, something like this

```
A "\t" 13 "\t" R
W "\t" 234 "\t" H
```

What I tried and ofcourse it failed was

```
tr "" "\t" <test.txt>test2.txt
```

could you suggest something in bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

does this work?

```
sed 's/^./&\t/;s/.$/\t&/' file
```

Comment: If someone needed to do this with Perl (e.g. on Windows) it would be `perl -pe's/^./$&\t/;s/.$/\t$&/' file`. (If you want it to modify the file in-place you could add the [`-i`](http://p3rl.org/perlrun) switch)

Answer (score 2):

Since it was tagged in your question, you could user `perl` like:

```
perl -pi -e 's/(.)(.*)(.)/\1\t\2\t\3/' < in.txt > out.txt
```

Be careful about using the same file for input and output like your `tr` example. Remember, your shell will open both the input and output files *before* executing the command. The output file is *clobbered*, and so when your command runs, it finds an empty file. There are tools to work around this, like `sponge`, but it's just as easy to use two different file names.

Answer (score 2):

Pure Bash; using substring expansion:

```
while read line ; do
  echo -e "${line:0:1}\t${line:1:-1}\t${line: -1:1}"
done < data.txt
```